# Makefile error that works fine in console

Tags: c, makefile

I am building a makefile that runs a series of tests and adds the results to a file.  In the makefile I have this set up as:

```
runtests:
    rm -f results.txt
    cardtest1 > results.txt
    cardtest2 >> results.txt
    cardtest3 >> results.txt   
    cardtest4 >> results.txt   
    unittest1 >> results.txt    
    unittest2 >> results.txt
    unittest3 >> results.txt
    unittest4 >> results.txt
```

Now I am able to run all of the above commands in this or any other order (provided the results.txt file exists for the appends) without problem.  However, no matter what test is run after rm -f results.txt when it is in the makefile, it will always generate an error.

```
 flip1 ~/src/dominion-base 161% make all
 rm -f results.txt
 cardtest1 > results1.txt
 make: *** [runtests] Error 1
```

I have been tinkering with it for an hour (originally had all as >> but realized that an append apparently does not create a file that doesn't exist), and I am really unsure of what exactly is wrong with my makefile.

Comment: Error 1 is not a Make error it is a GCC error

Comment: in using the shell directly, > gives an error if the file exists and >> gives an error if it doesn't;

     @Nullpointer, how would it be a gcc error if the code is already compiled at that point and compiling or running it outside the makefile doesn't error out?

Comment: `make` uses `sh` as default shell, which runs the above commands fine, with no errors. Which shell are you using? You may add `echo ${SHELL}` to your `runtests` directive. And considering Nullpointer's comment, it's better for you to post your makefile without suppressing directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

```
make: *** [runtests] Error 1
```

means that while make was building the target `runtests`, one of the commands that it ran exited with an error code of `1`.  In POSIX (and make), any exit code other than 0 is considered a failure; only 0 means that the command succeeded.

So make will examine the exit code of the program it invokes (which is the only thing it has to go on) and if it's not 0 it assumes the command failed, and it stops the build.

In the above I would say that your program `cardtest1` is exiting with an exit code of 1.  You can test this by running (from your shell command line):

```
cardtest1
echo $?
```

because the shell puts the exit code of the just-completed program into the shell variable `$?`.  If it's not 0, then you need to modify your `cardtest1` program to ensure that the exit code is set properly.

Comment: all of my tests are returning 1, even though I don't have an explicit return.  I have added a return 0 to the end of all of them, and that seems to clear this up.

Comment: If you don't have an explicit return then (according to the C standard) the return value is undefined.  It's a programming error to define a function, even `main`, that has a non-`void` return type (`int main()`), and then not return anything.  Most compilers will warn about that (at least if you enable warnings).

Comment: @MadScientist C has allowed you to omit the `return` statement for the `main` function since C99 as long as the return type for the function is compatible with `int`. It will automatically return 0 if the end of `main` is reached before a `return` statement is encountered. If not compatible with `int`, the status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear about which standard.  That was a particularly silly decision on the part of the C99 committee IMO.  Nevertheless it's only true of C99 (and later) conforming compilers.  GCC, for example, only conforms if you specifically request it by adding `-std=...`.  And Microsoft C _can't_ support the C99 standard.  So it's always best to use the `return 0;` explicitly.

Comment: normally I am explicit with returns (the shell I use to start most of my c files with a main function has a return 0 at the end of it), but I copied a different file to get started, and it lacked the explicit return.